# what does the sum of 3 sides of a 3-d rectangular box mean?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, self-learning

I want to understand what knowing "the sum of 3 sides of a 3-d rectangular box" means.

The question was from my job interview. I didn't really understand what they meant but later, I just had an idea that the company is an organization for a fulfilment warehouse business and they need to calculate for the right box to contain items.

After the interview, I went to the company's website and they were saying the cover boxes to contain items are selected by the sum of 3 sides of a 3-d rectangular box. What is a value of a side, here?

----------------------------------------------------Updated------------------------------------------------------

But by knowing the sum of 3 sides of a 3-d cover box, how do we know an item can be contained in the a bigger 3-d box?

----------------------------------------The way I have understood ------------------------------------------

They say "the sum of 3 sides" and my understanding of the sum of 3 sides is that each side has its own length and each side of the cover box must be bigger than the item case, otherwise the item cannot fit in the cover box.

Can somebody tell me what it means? and I am not sure the way I interpret is correct or not.

Comment: Maybe they mean the sum of the length, breadth, and height of the box?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3184907/177399

Comment: Thank you for the link and it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please be more clear ? are you sure that it is the sum of the three sides of the rectangle rather than the sum of the square of the three sides ?

The sum of the sides of the rectangle is l + b + h,

square root of the square of three sides ie $ \sqrt {l^2 + b^2 + h^2} $ gives the dimension of the diagonal which gives a fair idea of the maximum length of an object that can be placed diagonally into the box.

Look at the image below

[image]

d is the length of the diagonal and it is the maximum length of the object that the box can accommodate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just rechecked what they say on their website and it is the sum. However, your answer appears more to me. Maybe they just use "the sum" without specifically exposing it. But what still wonders me is that how I can tell a box can contain another box by knowing the sum of 3 sides?

Comment: Can you please share the website link so that I can take a look ??

Comment: it is not English. How they decide the kind of a cover box is that they measure the the sum of 3 sides of an item and if the sum of 3 sides of an item is less than the sum of 3 sides of a cover box, then they recommend that specific cover box. My translation is not wrong I guess. Can you please explain what the euclidean distance really means in your answer and what do you mean by "the dimension of the diagonal", I half way understood and I am kind of struggling.

Comment: Please look at the updated answer @StoryMay

Comment: Before the update, I tried to understand what your initial answer meant and I understood what meant in your initial answer. Thank you very much for the update.

Answer (score 1):

It's $w+h+d$ where $w$ is the width, $h$ is the height and $d$ is the depth of the box.